# Parallel.ForEach ends tasts but it shouldn't do it

Tags: c#

That is the fragment of my code:

```
Parallel.ForEach(companies, company =>
{
    using (DatabaseContext dbContextForTask = new DatabaseContextFactory().Create(company.ConnectionString))
    {
        CopingFilesService serviceCopingFilesService = new CopingFilesService(dbContextForTask);
        serviceCopingFilesService.CopyFiles(company.CompanyId);
    }
});
```

Each company can be on a different database. I pass to Parallel.ForEach about 20 companies - for each company I create Entity Framework DbContext and copy files.
At the beginning I see that files are being copied from 20 companies but after about 1 hour I see that files are being copies from only 2 companies. Tasks for the other companies ends but why? There are still files to copy.

Comment: This question is almost impossible to answer with the given information. You should instrument your code to wirte log files and evaluate what's going wrong.

Comment: There could be a few reasons for this, none of them are evident in the code you have shown. also TPL decides what it should do based on resources and many other factors. Lastly, Parallel.ForEach is not appropriate for IO bound tasks. consider using async await, or dataflow

Comment: Well, CopingFilesService stops to copy for some reason.

Comment: You may want to add some error handling, like try/catch inside _and_ around the .ForEach()